# store loop result in variable,python

Tags: python, list

i have a list of sentences called "data" and i carried out an operation of soundex.
 i dont know how to store it in a variable.. here is my code:

```
for line in data:

    for word in line.split():

        print jellyfish.soundex(word)
```

that gives me a list of soundex codes for all words..

how do i store the results in a variable?? i have tried:

```
data_new = [(jellyfish.soundex(word) for word in line.split()) for line in data]
```

but that did not help.

Comment: Try list comprehension instead of generator expression: `data_new = [[jellyfish.soundex(word) for word in line.split()] for line in data]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use list comprehension instead of generator expression:

```
data_new = [[jellyfish.soundex(word) for word in line.split()] for line in data]
```

Or, if you want flat list:

```
data_new = [jellyfish.soundex(word) for line in data for word in line.split()]
```

Comment: could i get back my original list from this??

Comment: @Sword, What do you mean the original list?

Comment: yeah.. for an entire intuition abt my problem check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21628391/replace-words-using-soundex-python

Comment: @Sword, If you mean get the `data` from the generated `data_new`. No you can't. (You may use `' '.joni(...)`, but it will not give you exactly same string because `str.split` remove consecutive whitespaces.)

Comment: so how do i get alon with it? i was thinking of computing and comparing the soundex in the for loop itself . if it is same , str.replace it with right spelling.. wats ur say?

Comment: @Sword, Do you want something like this: `data_new = [''.join(jellyfish.soundex(word) for word in line.split()) for line in data]` ?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the generator expression from within the comprehension:

```
data_new = [jellyfish.soundex(word) for line in data for word in line.split() ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the parentheses around `(jellyfish.soundex(word) for word in line.split())`, which is a generator expression (see for example [generator comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364802/generator-comprehension)). The result,

```
data_new = [jellyfish.soundex(word) for word in line.split() for line in data]
```

should give you what you seem to want.